# SwiftUI and saving with Core Data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI. I have button that a user can press and it will add 1 to an int. Each day I  reset the int to 0.

What is the best way to save the number of button presses every day so that I can display a calendar that shows how many times a user has pressed the button each day.

How could I save this in Core Data?

Comment: Do you know anything about Core Data, otherwise it might be a good idea to start by doing some tutorials and reading some articles about the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add an attribute in core data where you can add 1 to it whenever a user presses on the button.  You can set it to zero when you want to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are that simple then look into AppStorage, it will save the data as needed and re-render any views that rely on it.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("savedData") var myNumber = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(String(myNumber))
                .onTapGesture {
                    myNumber += 1
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants to save the count per day so not only is your solution incorrect it also uses UserDefaults in a way it is not intended to be used.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If I understand correctly it’s not an autosave but a manual increment, also why is saving to UserDefaults this way incorrect?

Comment: Yes it’s manual but it needs to be stored as a pair, date and count. UserDefaults should not be used for this kind of ever growing data set but for single properties who doesn’t grow in size or are updated to frequently (even if the frequency isn’t a problem here)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So CoreData then?